# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to let the user only read and write their own data. My rules are as follow(from the docs)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The uid for my user matches my document id but i still get the error:

> Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:
> FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or
> insufficient permissions.

My code for getting uid to document id

```
const handleSignUp = async () => {
      auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(async (UserCredentials) => {
        const user = UserCredentials.user;
        console.log("Registered with: ", user.email);

        try {
          const uidRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);

          const docRef = await setDoc(uidRef, {
            name: name,
            age: age,
            currentWeight: currentWeight,
            goalWeight: goalWeight,
          });

        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
        }
```

I am really lost as I have tried many different ways and all docs / answers on here do not work for me. I am guessing the error comes when i call snapshot in this code

```
const getUser = async() => {

    const subscriber = onSnapshot(usersRef, (snapshot) => {
      let user = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          user.push({...doc.data(), key: doc.id })
        })
        setUser(user);
        console.log(user);
    })
    return () => subscriber();
  };
```

I am just unsure as to what is exactly wrong here. Is it my rules? My snapshot?

Comment: How is `usersRef` initialized? Also: just before `onSnapshot`, test in your code whether its state meets the requirements of the rules, e.g. that the user is signed in.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was trying to implement this before doing it the way the docs say [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) and it wasnt working for me. I tried implementing the way you have show in your answer but it just results in the error **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.docs.forEach')**

Comment: The usersRef is just a reference to the users collection not with the uid like you have shown. When I use the uidRef it shows the error i previously mentioned but when I use usersRef it will console log my user like it is working but still throws the permissions error at the same time which is really confusing me. I am fairly new to react native and firebase so it could be something easy im missing.

Comment: First off: in the future when you're responding to an answer, please put the comment under that answer instead of on your question. It's quite hard to navigate the way you've posted it now. Second: does the explanation in my answer make sense, and do you understand why your initial code wouldn't work based on that? Third: once you use my code, you will no longer get back a `QuerySnapshot` but instead you get a `DocumentSnapshot`. So you no longer need a loop. I updated my answer to show how to handle the document.

Comment: Apologies I had realised that only after I posted! Yes it makes sense to write code which follows your rules so my querys will make sure user is logged in and uid matches. Thank you for updating the code it seemed to work on first look but I now realise that when my useEffect calls the function when the page loads I see `undefined` in my console but if I save that file it reloads and the user object can be seen in my console. Do you have any idea what this is about? Sorry for asking alot of questions and thanks for your time, im quite a  newbie at react native and firebase!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you get a `QuerySnapshot` result, I suspect that your code is reading the entire `users` collection. But as the documentation says [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but instead merely ensure that your code only tries to access data that it is permitted to.

So your code should only try to read the document of the currently signed in user.

```
const getUser = async() => {
  if (getAuth().currentUser) {
    const uidRef = doc(db, 'users', getAuth().currentUser.uid);

    const subscriber = onSnapshot(uidRef, (doc) => {
      setUser({...doc.data(), key: doc.id })
    })

    ...
  }
};
```