# How to write security rules for listing documents in the collection?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I want to query all the chats I'm a member of and listen to their updates.

Firestore structure is

```
/chats/{chatId}
```

I have the following query in my JavaScript application

```js
// cut

const chatsQuery = query(
  collection(firestore, "chats"),
  where('members', 'array-contains', userId),
  orderBy('lastActivity', 'desc'),
).withConverter(converter)


const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(chatsQuery , (snapshot) => snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => { /* ... */ }))

// cut
```

This is my security rules

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    match /chats/{chatId} {
      allow read: if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following error in console

> client.js?4d30:1 [2023-04-02T14:55:07.984Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.18.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]:
> evaluation error at L9:22 for 'list' @ L9

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I use firebase emulators

Comment: [Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, FirebaseError: [[code=permission-denied\]: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74804152/uncaught-error-in-snapshot-listener-firebaseerror-code-permission-denied-m) ??   (P.S. I use a search engine... )

Comment: The problem described in the link you provided seems to be similar but does not solve my problem

Comment: How is your `userId` populated? Do you get the same error if you use `getAuth().currentUser`?

Comment: `userId` is id taken from the `onAuthStateChange` (aka user.uid). I'm trying to test this rule when I have 0 documents inside my collection.

Comment: I don't know why if I add `debug(resource)` it shows me the following code `[debug] [2023-04-02T15:59:17.611Z] [debug] [2023-04-02T15:58:48.665Z] map_value { fields { key: "data" value { map_value { fields { key: "members" value { constraint_value { simple_constraints { comparator: LIST_CONTAINS value { string_value: "641bbe444e516fad2fb787b0" } } } } } } } } } }` Shouldn't be it empty?

Comment: I think I found the problem. Verifying if it functions properly...